# По разному отображаются страницы на Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Есть [сайт](http://demo.main-gifts.ru) сверстанный на *Bootstrap* в нем все станицы отображаются одинаково, за исключением каталога, не пойму почему. Каталог имеет другую ширину в отличии от всех страниц, это хорошо видно на большом разрешении экрана, или в масштабе.

Везде идет конструкция сетки на bootstrap на div: `container - container-wrapper - row` и пошли ячейки, в каталоге это `col-md-12 col-lg-12`, а в других разделах идет `col-md-3 col-md-9`. Что по сути одно и тоже, но отображается по разному. Прошу помощи, голову сломал.

[image: Вот пример, страница во всю ширину]

[image: Вот пример картинки когда каталог сжиматься]

Comment: вы хотя бы скриншоты приведите для примера на что смотреть

Comment: добавил скрины. Страницы должны быть одинаковые по ширине

Comment: вы про разницу в padding в 15пх ?

Comment: там где паддинга нет (ширина меньше), бутстрап не подключен

Comment: Спасибо! именно в подключении бутрсапа проблема была) Он по факту залит в шаблон, и его его повторно подключать не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение - данные блоки (показанные на изображении) обернуть в `div` с классом `.row`

Пример

```css
[class*=col-] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    left sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        slider
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->

    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        slider
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->

    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- обязательно должен быть родителем для col - row -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет, так не сработало. ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Александр - посмотри скрин, который я прикрепил, и сравните сейчас с вашим кодом на сайте в данном месте.